# Netplan gives usb error

Tags: ubuntu, usb, netplan

There is output of `netplan apply`:

```
usb usb2-port3: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: BMDA stat 0x64
ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
...
```

Netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 73.139.189.196/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 77.88.8.8
          - 62.112.113.170
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 100.81.203.212
  version: "2"
```